# TYPO3 extbase forward , redirect action

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

how can i redirect to a different action using redirect or forward functions ? My solution doesn't seem to work

```
public function listAction() {
    $products = $this->productRepository->findAll();
    $this->view->assign('products', $products);  
}

public function showAction() {
    $var = $this->request->getArgument('searchProduct');
    $foundProd = new \MyVendor\Inventory\Domain\Model\Product($var);      
    $prod = $this->productRepository->getProduct($foundProd);
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\DebugUtility::debug($prod);

    $this->view->assign('test',$prod);
    $this->redirect('list',NULL,NULL,array(''));
     // $this->forward('list',NULL, NULL, $this->request->getArguments());
}
```

In the view , i'm trying to show the foundProduct in the same page (not by creating a new file show.html)

```
 <f:widget.paginate objects="{products}" as="paginatedProducts" 
         configuration="{itemsPerPage: 10, insertAbove: 0, insertBelow: 1, maximumNumberOfLinks: 10}">
          <f:for each="{paginatedProducts}" as="productx"> 

                   <tr>    
                           <td align="top">{productx.uid}</td>
                           <td align="top">{productx.name}</td>
                           <td align="top"><f:format.crop maxCharacters="100">{productx.description}</f:format.crop></td>
                           <td align="top">{productx.quantity}</td>
                   </tr>
           </f:for>
                 </f:widget.paginate>
   </table>

</div>
<div class="col-sm-5">

<f:form method="post" controller="Inventory" action="show" name="searchProduct"  object="{searchProduct}">
<label> Product Name <span class="required"></span><br />
  <f:form.textfield property="name" /></label><br />
<f:form.submit class="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

```
<div>
<f:for each ="{test}" as ="p">
  <P>Numele produsului : {p.name}</P>
  <p>Descriere : {p.description}</p>
  <p>Cantitate :  {p.quantity} </p>
</f:for>
</div>
</div>
```

EDIT : [list.html file. Basically when i click Submit i want to show on the same page the product found from the database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO2AX.png)

[This is how it works atm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWuFd.png)

Comment: Your code seems to redirect to `listAction` every time you want to execute `showAction`. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: I would like that both actions are executed on the same page(.html file) . Typo3 kinda forces me to create a different .html file for each action , in my case list.html , and show.html . Instead of creating show.html I would like showAction to be executed in the list.html .

Comment: I can't get the idea behind it. The `showAction` should show something, mostly the detail of a record like the detail view in news extension. The only time I use redirects is when I e.g. update a record and go back to list after saving the changes. You should overthink your actions and what to do in there imho.

Comment: And for what do you need the showAction?

Comment: I guess the idea is to have both a list and a detailed view for a single item? If your concern is just to reuse the template you should read up on partials. If I get the idea behind your question right, they are the more elegant way to do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it won't work that way.
If you use `redirect` or `forward` the variable assignment is reset.

You can assign multiple Properties within the `listAction`:

```
public function listAction() {
    $products = $this->productRepository->findAll();

// from your showAction
    $var = $this->request->getArgument('searchProduct');
    $foundProd = new \MyVendor\Inventory\Domain\Model\Product($var);      
    $prod = $this->productRepository->getProduct($foundProd);


    $this->view->assignMultiple(
        array(
           'products' => $products,
           'test' => $prod
        )
    );  
}
```

This will fill the template you mentioned above

Comment: Did this but i get the following error : An argument "searchProduct" does not exist for this request.
More information regarding this error might be available online. Most probably the error is refering to this line : <f:form method="post" controller="Inventory" action="list" name="searchProduct"  object="{searchProduct}">